# how to convert query into laravel

Tags: laravel

How write below query into Laravel

```
$q=array();

$search="SELECT name,imgs FROM `files` WHERE (`show`='0' AND `name` LIKE '%".implode("%' ) or (`show`='0' AND name LIKE '%", $q)."%')";
```

Comment: This isn't even a valid query... What have you tried so far?

Comment: i m using it @ [Gamezwap.Net](http://gamezwap.net)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
File::select(['name','imgs'])
->where(['show'=>false])
->where('name', 'like', '"%".$q."%"')
->get();
```

Using eloquent

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your query right or wrong but if its working fine then u can use the following

in **controller**

```
use DB;
```

in the inside of **controller function**

```
$tt=DB::select('put your raw query here');
```

suppose for example

```
$tt=DB::select('select id, title, user_id, content, created_at from posts where user_id =? union  select id, title, user_id, description, created_at from recipes where user_id = ? order_by created_at desc',[$id,$id]');
```

or

```
$tt=DB::select('select * from tablename');
```

or

```
$tt=DB::select('SELECT name,imgs FROM `files` WHERE (`show`='0' AND `name` LIKE '%".implode("%' ) or (`show`='0' AND name LIKE '%", $q)."%')');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Laravel's DB facade. Place the php use at the top of the file. like this.

```
use DB;
```

And then in your method use the following method call on the DB facade.

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM table')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

use model:

```
    $name = $request->name ? '%' . $request->name . '%' : '';
    $model = ModelName::select('name','imgs')
             ->where(['show' => 0])
             ->where(function($q) use($name) {$q->where("name", "like", "$name");})
             ->get();
```

Hope that helps.